# Troubles Iterating Over A HashMap with JSF, MyFaces & Facelets

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, myfaces

I'm having some trouble looping over a HashMap to print out it's values to the screen.  Could someone double check my code to see what I'm doing wrong.  I can't seem to find anything wrong but there must be something.

In a servlet, I am adding the following to the request:

```
Map<String, String> facetValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
// Filling the map
req.setAttribute(facetField.getName(), facetValues);
```

In one case "facetField.getName()" evaluates to "discipline".  So in my page I have the following:

```
<ui:repeat value="${requestScope.discipline}" var="item">
  <li>Item: <c:out value="${item}"/>, Key: <c:out value="${item.key}"/>, Value: <c:out value="${item.item}"/></li>
</ui:repeat>
```

The loop is ran once but all the outputs are blank?!?  I would have at least expected something in item if it's gone over the loop once.  Checking the debug popup for Facelets, discipline is there and on the loop.  Printing it to the screen results in something that looks like a map to me (I've shortened the output) :

```
{300=0, 1600=0, 200=0, ... , 2200=0}
```

I've also tried with a c:forEach but I'm getting the same results.  So does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks for any input,
Lee

Comment: Can you clarify: Are you seeing "Item:, Key:, Value:" for each item in the map (but the actual values aren't printing)?

Comment: Not for every value. The loop is iterating just the once. But I'm pretty sure I am passing the correct HashMap into the loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<ui:repeat>` only accepts List or DataModel, not Sets or Maps. This is on the roadmap for JSF 2.1.

Answer (score 12):

with el 2.2 support you can iterate maps like below.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.stats.keySet().toArray()}" var="x">
    <h:outputText value="#{myBean.stats.get(x)}" /><br />
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Cheers Berkay, saved me a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Three things occur to me:

1.

The [documentation for ui:repeat](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template) doesn't say it (it only says *List*), but I see UIRepeat uses [DataModel](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/model/package-summary.html) as its model (in the manner of h:dataTable). *Map* will not be automatically wrapped with a *DataModel* type - the type is not implicitly supported. You will need to either make the value an instance of your own *DataModel* implementation or provide them as an implicitly supported type (e.g. *java.util.List*).

2.

I am not sure what you intend these values to map to:

```
${item}
${item.key}
${item.item}
```

If you change "discipline" to be of type *List<Map.Entry<String,String>>*, you could bind to the [key and value](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) properties:

```
${item.key}
${item.value}
```

You can create your list like so:

```
Map<String, String> facetValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
// Filling the map
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> discipline
        = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>>(facetValues.entrySet());
```

3.

The [FAQ suggests](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Projects/FaceletsFAQ#Why_doesn_t_my_c_if_ui_repeat_ui) that JSTL tags are only evaluated at component tree creation time. It is unclear to me whether using c:out as a child of ui:repeat will work properly. You might need to use h:outputText instead. (I could be wrong about this, of course - I have not tried it.)

---

> In a servlet, I am adding the following to the request

That sounds like an odd way to put something into request scope in JSF, but I'll trust that you know what you're doing!