# richfaces datagrid with 2 backing bean lists

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I want to make a rich:datagrid using 2 lists from my backing bean instead of one.

So instead of :

```html
<rich:dataGrid columns="1" width="100%" value="#{MyBean.myList1}" var="listobj1" iterationStatusVar="it" elements="10">
```

I want :

```html
<rich:dataGrid columns="1" width="100%" value="#{MyBean.myList1}, #{MyBean.myList2}" var="listobj1, listobj2" iterationStatusVar="it" elements="10">
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you just want to iterate over all values of myList1 and myList2? In that case I'd use `MyBean.myUnion` as value and have a getter that just says `List l = new ArrayList(myList1); l.addAll(myList2); return l;`. But your use of `var` confuses me - what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Sorry about that, should probably specify why.Basically I have 2 Lists on the backing bean which are Lists of POJOs(List<myPojo>).Now all I want is to be able to reference attributes of the POJO in the datagrid.So basically I want to be able to add <h:outputText value="#{listObj1.name} : #{listObj2.name}"/> inside the datagrid.

Comment: Is there a 1:1 mapping between listObj1 and listObj2? In that case you'd probably be able to use a `Map<pojo1,pojo2>` and iterate over that. Though that's kind of a hassle with JSF, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552804/uirepeat-doesnt-work-with-map and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10934074/785663

Comment: Hmm the map is a nice idea,but unfortunetly using a map wont work as I get these as lists and they can become quite long so converting them to a map will take long,which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, that's not possible because `value` must point to an Object (not a composite string).

Based on the fact that you only have those two lists and there seems to be a implicit mapping, I'd iterate over one and reference the other from the loop:

```
<rich:dataGrid columns="1" value="#{MyBean.myList1}" rowKeyVar="k" var="elem" elements="10">
  <h:outputText value="#{elem.name}: #{MyBean.myList2[k].name}" />
</rich:dataGrid>
```

Comment: Is a certain Servlet,EL,JSF version needed for this?

Comment: Not that I know of. Though I've always been using a EL-2.2 implementation (Jboss EL).

Comment: I'm accepting this as answer so long as it will probably work,having some other problems with my code so can't test now.

Comment: JBoss EL is an EL 2.1 implementation which enhances EL 2.1 with the method-incovation feature as available in EL 2.2. It is not an EL 2.2 implementation.

Comment: I found no pratical difference so far, but thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Ok I have confirmed that this works,I am using MyFaces 2.0.17 and RichFaces 4.3.1.I have no standalone EL library so whatever version is needed for this must be in one of those two libraries.Sadly I can't vote up the answer due to low rep.